# Proving that $D$ is dense in $(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $G \subset (0, \infty) $ and is not bounded. If we define set $D$ as below

$$ D = \Big\{x \in (0, \infty) : \exists A \subset \mathbb{N} \text{ not bounded s.t. } \forall n \in A, nx \in G \Big\} $$

Prove that $D$ is dense in $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: n is a natural number?

Comment: @polbos Yes, n is a natural number

Answer (score 1):

First show that $ D = (0, \infty) $.

Then show that a set with no isolated points is dense in itself.

Hence $D$ is dense in $(0, \infty)$.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: @FreeMind I have edited the answer accordingly and also suggested a rewording of the question to make it clearer.